# How to see Python source files on Windows if it's in hidden folder

Tags: windows, installation, python

I formatted my computer couple of days ago and re-installed Python again. The version is 3.5 now.

The problem is, Python installed itself into AppData which is a hidden folder. I tried to un-hidden it but I couldn't. Before format I could do it. But it's not the main problem actually, I can't reach AppData so I can't see the source files of Python.

Why Python installed itself automatically into AppData instead of Program Files or etc. ? How can I fix this problem, don't want to uninstall and reinstall Python again.

Comment: You don't need to unhide the directory to manually navigate to the directory.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't understand your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to enter the path in the location bar manually:

[image]

then press enter:

[image]

Or,

[image]

Choose "Install for all users":

[image]